# Code igniter how to add constant in config folder

Tags: codeigniter

This is how, code igniter folder path is

```
application->config
system
x -> y -> z
```

I want to create a constant for folder x,y,z.

How do I do this in code igniter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create constant inside constant.php.. that is why codeigniter has this file for.. have a look inside..

application/config/constants.php....

setting it

```
define('FOLDERPATH', 'yourpath');
```

getting if

```
echo FOLDERPATH
```

Comment: I created a constant define('FOLDERPATH', 'http://localhost/x/');
in constant.php. Now, How do I use this in my view.

Comment: just call FOLDERPATH.. whereever you want

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Custom Configuration Variables and Values in CodeIgniter**

To keep things tidy, I in my config folder, I create a second configuration file called `config_aux.php` (aux is short for auxiliary).

In my autoload.php file, I add: `$autoload['config'] = array('config_aux');`

In my `config_aux.php` file I add things like:

```
$config['user_status'] = array(
                              '1' => 'Active',
                              '0' => 'Inactive'
                              );
```

and for constants:

```
define('FORMAT_MYSQL_DATE','%Y-%m-%d');
```

My constants are global but that does not bother me.

In your case, you want a constant to represent your folder path "x/y/z"